# Angular Kendo Grid Field Name gives a warning "Grid Field name is not a valid identifier"

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

here is the exact warning which I am getting

```
Grid column field name 'Access Request Privilege' does not look like a valid JavaScript identifier.
                Identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters (including "$" or "_"), and may not start with a digit.
                Please use only valid identifier names to ensure error-free operation.
```

and here is the code which i have written for the kendo grid to dynamicall get the names

```
<kendo-grid-column field="{{gridColumn2}}" title="Access Request Privilege" width="110">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
          <div [innerHTML]="dataItem.AccessPrivilegeName"></div>
        </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
```

how can we tackle those warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the mistake in this code I had noticed was that instead of field I should have written Title and instead of title I should have written name.

So below is my solution which worked and I didn't have any warning in the console.

```
 <kendo-grid-column title="{{gridColumn2}}" name="Access Request Privilege" width="110">
           <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
               <div [innerHTML]="dataItem.AccessPrivilegeName"></div>
           </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: Why was that a mistake?  The [Telerik docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/define-columns/) docs state that you should use 'field' and 'title' respectively, but I have the same issue